# Atom - проблема с регистром букв

Tags: atom

Когда я в атоме пишу issampavailble - без регистра букв(должно быть isSampAvailable) то вариант, подсказка isSampAvailable не показывается. Как можно решить эту проблему? Как сделать игнорирование регистра букв?

Comment: А откуда atom должен узнать, какой регистр является правильным?

Comment: В VSCode он сам узнает. Не в зависимости от регистра букв он выдает возможные варианты